# Vtiger6.4 workflow Every time record is modified not working?

Tags: email, workflow, vtigercrm

I have vtiger6.4 installed and smtp configuration is also done.When I create a new lead it sends the mail.I have created a Workflow for lead and selected Every time the record is modified email should be send to the assigned to.But it is not working.Suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are to option to trigger workflow on save event.

> 1. Every Time Record is saved
> 2. Every Time Record is modified

First is

> **Every Time Record is saved**

This means even no field is updated and you just click save it will trigger workflow event.

You have selected

> **Every time the record is modified**

So that means atleast one Field must be updated using Record Model Class. If you are updating it using query then Workflow will not be Triggered.

Now you have to choose which trigger event you want to choose. If still you have problem then possible that you have set condition in 2nd step. You can provide more details so can help you in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Vtiger Email on workflows send email via cronjobs.

Read more at:
[vTigerCRM 7 - Scheduler isn't running any cron jobs unless manually triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292976/vtigercrm-7-scheduler-isnt-running-any-cron-jobs-unless-manually-triggered)