# vTigerCRM 7 - Scheduler isn't running any cron jobs unless manually triggered

Tags: php, cron, scheduler, vtiger, vtigercrm

I'm running vTiger 7.0 and I noticed on the first of the month, none of my invoices were created. I then took a look at the Scheduler and noticed that the "Last scan started" and "Last scan ended" fields show that none of the cron jobs had fired in days. The cron jobs are scheduled to fire in 15 minute intervals, with the exception of "RecurringInvoice" which runs every 12 hours.

If I visit /myvtigerinstall/vtigercron.php, the cron jobs will all fire but nobody wants to have to manually run cron jobs!

Has anyone had a similar issue before with vTiger?
I'm not exactly sure how to troubleshoot this error effectively and efficiently. I've checked permissions and they all seem to be in order.

Comment: did it worked and now has stopped work ? Or did it never work, and you maybe forgot to setup your web server for launching the cron ? It's not enought to parameter a cron in vTiger, you have to setup the bot that will launch the cron...

Comment: I didn't realize they weren't running until I checked on the 4th of the month. Hmm that makes sense though, perhaps I have to setup the bot to launch the cron then. I'll do some Googling lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed vTiger CRM on a dedicated server, you maybe have added a line in linux crontab so that the cron executes...

For instance :

```
 * * * * * sh home/vtiger/vtigerCRM5/apache/htdocs/vtigerCRM/cron/vtigercron.sh
```

If the cron doesn't launch automatically, it means it's not launched by the cron bot...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look now!

Comment: Please keep me in touch if the problem comes here ;-)

Comment: Nailed it! The line was there, but the wrong user was being used. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Vtiger minimum cron frequency is 15 minutes.
Add the following line in crontab

```
*/15 * * * * wget -O- --spider "http://vtigercrmurl/vtigercron.php" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or use the following free services

https://www.easycron.com/

https://cron-job.org